# JQuery Change value of custom attribute in script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script tag with a custom attribute like this:

```
<script myattribute="" src="..." />
```

How can I change the value of "myattribute" with jQuery?

Comment: I don't understand why you would use a custom attribute in a script attribute? What is it you want to do with this custom attribute? What's its use?

Comment: Using it as a tidy way of passing parameters to a js file

Comment: Please don't post the same question multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use name selector `script` like :

```
$("script:first").attr('myattribute', 'new_avalue');
```

Or you can go trough all your tags script using `each` method :

```
$("script").each(function(){
    $(this).attr('myattribute', 'value_you_want');
})
```

Hope this helps.